# Get last element of a OneToMany relation with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, one-to-many

I'm having a "Student" model that is related to many "Transfer" elements in Symfony2 using Doctrine.

How can I access the last "Transfer" element that is related to the current "Student" in an efficient way?

That is to say for example, creating a method like "getLastTransfer()" in the "Student" class.

I have hears that it is not recommended to use the entity manager inside of a modal in order to be able to use dependency injections on it etc...

Thank you

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Granted that your `Transfer` entity has a `date` field, `Student` class will look like:

```
class Student
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Transfer" mappedBy="student")
     * @OrderBy({"date" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $transfers;

    // ...

}
```

The transfers are stored in a [`ArrayCollection`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.2/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html), so just call:

```
$student -> getTransfers() -> last();
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks just like what am looking for. Gonna try it right away.

Comment: `getTransfers()` gets all relations and then we take first?